# How can I use osm2po to calculate distance matrix in Km?

Tags: osm2po

How can I use osm2po to calculate distance matrix in Km? There is an example that calculates distance matrix in time but I cannot make it turn into kilometers. I dont understand how should I use the int[] path parameter into the calcPathLength function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is laid out by Carsten in this post and comments:
[How to speed up osm2po when using as java lib?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56646/how-to-speed-up-osm2po-when-using-as-java-lib)

I used the same code from Carsten's answer and just modified the last for loop to look like this. Works like a charm.

```
for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
          int x = z + y;
            if (x >= n) x -= n;

            matrix[y][x] = -1;
            if (router.isVisited(vertexIds[x])) {
                int[] path=router.makePath(vertexIds[x]);
                matrix[y][x] = graph.calcPathLength(path);  
            }
        }
```

So instead of getting the cost to the vertexIds[x], what we do is get the path (which is just an array of all the vertices visited to reach vertexIds[x], and then get the length of that path from the calcPathLength() function. 
Note: the matrix called matrix must be declared as double.

Comment: See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80994/graph-traverse-maximum-targetids